# Mongo aggregation exclude null fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation pipeline that does `$first` on multiple fields.

However, in some cases these fields are not present. In these cases, the field's value is returned as `null`. I need a way to exclude these fields.

I tried to use `$ifNull` in the `$project` stage, but it set the value of the fields to `false` instead of excluding them.

**Group stage:**

```
{
  _id: null,
  thisExists: {
    $first: "$thisExists"
  },
  thisDoesNotExist: {
    $first: "$thisDoesNotExist"
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
{
    _id:null,
    thisExists:"I exist",
    thisDoesNotExist:null
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out.

In `$project` stage, `$ifNull` should return `"$false"` instead of `false`

```
{
  thisExists: { $ifNull : ["$thisExists","$false"]},
  thisDoesNotExist : {$ifNull : ["$thisDoesNotExist","$false"]}
}
```

This will remove the fields that are null.

If someone has a better and easier answer, it would be great. I would prefer not to put so many fields in `$project` even though its dynamically.

Comment: MongoDB suggests using `$$REMOVE` for conditional removals https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#conditionally-exclude-fields. But `$false` works just as well :)